How can I override soft switch on dehumidifier so I can turn it on using a timer
My dehumidifier is switched on using a touchpad which controls its startup sequence. If I plug it in and supply current nothing happens until I turn it on using the touchpad. So I cannot cause it to switch on by using a simple timer plug/socket. The dehumidifier is the desiccant type so it needs to power up/down in a particular way. I would like to control it using a microcontroller timer circuit to come on at my chosen interval. I haven’t tried to take it apart and hack into the electronics because I lack the ability. However, apart from waiting for the manufacturer to incorporate this feature into a newer model, how feasible would such a hack be? It’s consumer grade domestic machine and I am a (many years ago) qualified electronics service tech so aware of danger of electricity. I would like to control it using an arduino or similar in conjunction with humidity sensor. Best wishes to all readers

Unless you are able to post a schematic of your dehumidifier, it will be difficult for anyone to give you advice for the modification you seek.

attach a hobby servo the the outside of the control panel in such a way that it can press the button

Commercial WiFi-triggered button pressers exist for this very reason. If you need to slide anything across a screen, it will be far more difficult, but a press would work. When I bought my dehumidifier, I asked about exactly this scenario so I could just have a switch on the AC side and it would just resume to last setting when AC power came back. Zero cost to the manufacturer to have good UX this way.

This question was answered by winny. I found many switch button pusher gadgets controlled by voice or bluetooth etc on aliexpress. Thanks for all comments
